# tablayout fragment's content not updating

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I have an activity with a `TabLayout`. When I go to my 2nd activity where I add some datas which are used in 1st activity and I come back, I need like 5-10 sec and a lot of swipes fot allowing the 1st activity fragment to be updated.

This is how I use the

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        setTitle("La mia settimana:");


        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        choosenDate = calendar.getTime();

        viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem((dayOfWeek == 1 ? 7 : dayOfWeek - 1));
    }
```

My adapter is the following:

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(2);
                break;
            case 1:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(3);
                break;
            case 2:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(4);
                break;
            case 3:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(5);
                break;
            case 4:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(6);
                break;
            case 5:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(7);
                break;
            case 6:
                choosenDate = GetDateFromDayWeek(8);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        HomePageTabFragment homePageTabFragment = new HomePageTabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("date", globalDateFormat.format(choosenDate));
        args.putInt("day", dayOfWeek);
        homePageTabFragment.setArguments(args);
        return homePageTabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Lun";
            case 1:
                return "Mar";
            case 2:
                return "Mer";
            case 3:
                return "Gio";
            case 4:
                return "Ven";
            case 5:
                return "Sab";
            case 6:
                return "Dom";
            default:
                return "Giorni settimana";
        }
    }
}
```

I always call the same fragment, with a Bundle of arguments.

I'm not gonna post the fragment, because it's really long and not relevant.
I just explain what he does: He take from db all entities, he sum some data's columns and he shows those datas inside the list.

now, my problem is the following:

In the 2nd activity I add an item to a list, and I save it in local db.

When i come back to my 1st activity, the datas (which are relative to ALL entities in db) should be updated.

The datas need like 20 sec of gestures before getting updated.
How can I solve this?

Comment: In the activities **onResume()** method try updating the fragments.

Comment: how should i do it? my problem is that the fragment is not in xml, because it is only in viewpager :S

Comment: You can update in fragments **onResume()**, because it will be called.

Comment: I didn't know it would have been fired! thanks, i resolved by reloading fragment inside his own onResume method :) if you answer i will vore it as correct :)